# How do I initialize the tinyusb submodule in my pico-sdk checkout?

Tags: usb, serial, pi-pico

I'm having a problem with the Raspberry Pi Pico hello world example using the C/C++ SDK on Ubuntu. When I drag and drop the hello_usb.uf2 binary the USB drive connection to the Pico terminates as expected, but when I run "minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyACM0" in my terminal window it returns to the command line after a few seconds without displaying any output from the Raspberry Pi Pico.

I noticed the following warning in the "Getting Started with Raspberry Pi Pico" online document which may be the source of my problem.

> If you have not initialised the tinyusb submodule in your pico-sdk checkout then USB CDC serial, and other USB functions and example code, will not work as the SDK will contain no USB functionality.

**Question**: How do I initialize the tinyusb submodule in my pico-sdk checkout?

Answer (score 2):

The tinyUsb is linked as a submodule of pico-sdk repository so, in order to compile it you will have to initialize it using git.

To initialize the tinyusb submodule you need to enter in your pico-sdk directory and run the following command line:

```
git submodule update --init
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a basic working app included in the pico-sdk. Under pico-sdk, look in lib/tinyusb/examples/device/cdc_dual_ports. Build the UF2 file for this, and push the UF2 file to the Pico board. The board will reboot itself and `/dev/ttyACM0` will become available on your native Linux system. You can then use minicom as you wrote above. This example program sends the typed characters back as lower-case; that's how you know the program is working.

The procedure for building the uf2 file:

```
$ cd  $PICO_SDK_PATH/lib/tinyusb/examples/device/cdc_dual_ports
$ mkdir build && cd build
$ cmake .. && make -j4
```

You'll get a fresh uf2 file in the build directory.